# Create dataframe from iteration result

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

datas1 = [{'A':10, 'B':100}, {'A':11,'B':-210}, {'A':12,'B':120}, {'A':14, 'B':30}]
datas2 = [{'A':25, 'B':90}, {'A':11,'B':-50}, {'A':110,'B':(-15)}, {'A':5, 'B':65}]
datas3 = [{'A':5, 'B':-100}, {'A':19,'B':210}, {'A':12,'B':-300}, {'A':14, 'B':30}]

for i in [datas1, datas2, datas3]:

    df = pd.DataFrame(i)
    df['CUMSUM'] = (df['B'].cumsum())

    if (df['CUMSUM'] < -100).any():      
        print(df.loc[df['CUMSUM'] < -100, :].head(1))
        print ("")  
    else:       
        print(df.loc[df['CUMSUM'] >= -100, :].tail(1))
        print ("")
```

What would be the code to create a new dataframe with the results obtained in this program?

Comment: Umm, if this runs then you do already create new dataframes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This aggregates all the output into one dataframe. I create a dictionary, assign key-values to the dictionary from each result, and then finally concatenate them.

```
import pandas as pd

datas1 = [{'A':10, 'B':100}, {'A':11,'B':-210}, {'A':12,'B':120}, {'A':14, 'B':30}]
datas2 = [{'A':25, 'B':90}, {'A':11,'B':-50}, {'A':110,'B':(-15)}, {'A':5, 'B':65}]
datas3 = [{'A':5, 'B':-100}, {'A':19,'B':210}, {'A':12,'B':-300}, {'A':14, 'B':30}]

results = {}

for idx, i in enumerate([datas1, datas2, datas3]):

    df = pd.DataFrame(i)
    df['CUMSUM'] = (df['B'].cumsum())

    if (df['CUMSUM'] < -100).any():
        results[idx] = df.loc[df['CUMSUM'] < -100, :].head(1)
        print(results[idx])
        print ("")

    else:
        results[idx] = df.loc[df['CUMSUM'] >= -100, :].tail(1)
        print(results[idx])
        print ("")

result = pd.concat(list(results.values()), ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: It works great! Thanks!!